# ggplot: colour points by groups based on user defined colours

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scatter-plot, color-codes

I am trying to define the colours of groups of points plotted in ggplot.  I adapted code from this post:

[Color ggplot points based on defined color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827193/color-ggplot-points-based-on-defined-color-codes)

but as soon as I have more than one row defined by the same grouping variable (rather than a separate colour for each row), the code fails, and I can't figure out why. Below is a reproducible example:

```
#create some data
zone  <- c("E","E","C","C","C","E","E") #grouping variable
col <- c(50,100,150,200,250,300,350) #x variable
D <- c(.4,.45,.20,.22,.30,.31,.35) #y variable
df1 <- data.frame(zone, D, col); df1

#create a colour scheme based on grouping variable 'zone'
zone <-c("E","C")
color.codes<-as.character(c("#3399FF", "#FF0000"))
color.names<-c("blue", "red")
df2=data.frame(zone, color.codes, color.names); df2

# merge color specifications with data
df <-merge(df1,df2, by=("zone"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE); df
```

The data then look like this:

```
zone    D   col color.codes color.names
C     0.20  150     #FF0000         red
C     0.22  200     #FF0000         red
C     0.30  250     #FF0000         red
E     0.40   50     #3399FF        blue
E     0.45  100     #3399FF        blue
E     0.31  300     #3399FF        blue
E     0.35  350     #3399FF        blue
```

The goal is to produce a plot where points in zone 'C' are red and those in 'E' are blue, but using the code from the example cited everything is plotted in red:

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(col, D, colour = zone))+ 
  geom_point() 
p + scale_colour_manual(breaks = df$zone, values = df$color.codes)
```

Can anyone see the fatal flaw, why this code won't work across groups in this way?
Thanks so much in advance

Answer (score 17):

You are somewhere between two different solutions.

One approach is to not put the colors into the `df` data frame and specify the mapping between `zone` and desired color in the scale call:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(col, D, colour = zone))+ 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(values=setNames(color.codes, zone))
```

[image]

Note that this does not use `color.codes` or `color.names` from `df`, nor does it use `df2` directly (though it does use the columns that are used to make `df2`; if you have something like `df2` and not the columns separately, you can use `setNames(df2$color.codes, df2$zone)` instead).

The other approach maps color directly to the color codes and uses `scale_color_identity`, but then has to go through some additional labeling to get the legend right.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(col, D, colour = color.codes)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_identity("zone", breaks=color.codes, labels=zone, guide="legend")
```

[image]

The first is, in my opinion, the better solution.

Answer (score 6):

It works if you use `unique` and `as.character`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(col, D, colour = zone))+ 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = df$zone, 
                      values = unique(as.character(df$color.codes)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sven beat me by a few secs, but slightly different:

```
df.unique <- unique(df[, c("zone", "color.names")])
p + scale_colour_manual(breaks = df.unique$zone, values = as.character(df.unique$color.names))
```