# How to control label color depending on fill darkness of bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a stacked bar plot, labelled with `geom_text`. To increase the visibility of the labels, I want to set the label color to either white or black depending of the 'darkness' of their background, i.e. the fill color of the bars. Thus, darker bars should have a white label, and lighter bars should have a black label.

I started with code from the question [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2), the answer to the question [Is there a is light or is dark color function in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437263/is-there-a-is-light-or-is-dark-color-function-in-r/49437644#49437644). On top of that I'd like to show the label of the data value in 'white' or 'black' depending whether the stacked bar fill color is dark or not dark respectively.

I made two attempts. The first is using `aes(colour=...)` of the `geom_text` function but this one fails ... why?.

The second attempt is using the function `scale_colour_manual`. But here the stacked bar lines are also "coloured" using the black or white toggling setting.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

Year      <- c(rep(c("2006-07", "2007-08", "2008-09", "2009-10"), each = 4))
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Frequency <- c(168, 259, 226, 340, 216, 431, 319, 368, 423, 645, 234, 685, 166, 467, 274, 251)
Data      <- data.frame(Year, Category, Frequency)

isDark <- function(color) {
  (sum(grDevices::col2rgb(color) *c(299, 587,114))/1000 < 123)
}

## control the color assignments
paletteName <- 'Set1' # 'Dark2'
colorsPerCat <- brewer.pal(name=paletteName,n=4)
names(colorsPerCat) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

## First attempt
Data$LabelColor <- as.character(as.vector(sapply(unlist(colorsPerCat)[Data$Category], function(color) { if (isDark(color)) 'white' else 'black' })))
Data
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(colour=LabelColor), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorsPerCat)
p

## Second attempt
labelColoursPerCat <- sapply(as.vector(colorsPerCat), function(color) { if (isDark(color)) 'white' else 'black' })
names(labelColoursPerCat) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency, colour = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorsPerCat) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = labelColoursPerCat)
p
```

Comment: `p + scale_color_identity()`?

Comment: You may also give due [credit to @42- for the `isDark` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49437644/1851712)

Comment: @Henrik Sorry yes forgot :)

Comment: @Henrik I didn’t quite get what scale_color_identity is good got here

Comment: When I looked at your "Data" in "First attempt", it seemed like you already had the actual colors intended for `geom_text` in a variable ("LabelColor") ("_i.e. it already represents aesthetic values that ggplot2 can handle directly_";  from `?scale_color_identity`). See also [Using a pre-defined color palette in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079264/using-a-pre-defined-color-palette-in-ggplot) and [ggplot: colour points by groups based on user defined colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536835/ggplot-colour-points-by-groups-based-on-user-defined-colours)

Comment: There may well be easier ways to create "Data", but _given_ the data you already have, it seems that you may use `scale_color_identity`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways to solve this issue by playing with `geom_bar` **color** or **size**:

```
Data$LabelColor <- as.factor(Data$LabelColor)
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency, colour = LabelColor)) +
              geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black") +
              geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
              scale_fill_manual(values = colorsPerCat) +  
              scale_colour_manual(values = levels(Data$LabelColor)) +
              guides(colour = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
Data$LabelColor <- as.factor(Data$LabelColor)
p <- ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Category, label = Frequency, colour=LabelColor)) +
              geom_bar(stat = "identity", size = 0) +
              geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
              scale_colour_manual(values = levels(Data$LabelColor)) +
              scale_fill_manual(values = colorsPerCat) +  
              guides(colour = FALSE)
```

[image]